# ASP.NET MVC Error in non user code, how do I debug it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Anyone have any idea how I start debugging this?
Below is what the browser is showing when the error occurs.

I've just cut and paste it below.

Seems the error is in an auto generated temporary file.

---

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Source Error:


Line 240:            #line default
Line 241:            #line hidden
Line 242:            @__w.Write("\r\n\r\n    <p>\r\n        ");
Line 243:            
Line 244:            #line 15 "K:\Projects\GroupTargets_01\Views\Group\Index.aspx"

Source File: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c52144fb\cf3eebf6\App_Web_index.aspx.1dacda6f.ihdui7sw.0.cs    Line: 242 


Show Detailed Compiler Output:

Show Complete Compilation Source:


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: Please add the corresponding source code! And your code is missing a ) so this is quite easy to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in your view page code for `K:\Projects\GroupTargets_01\Views\Group\Index.aspx`. The code you're seeing in the error message is what those `<@ ... @>` tags get turned into.